# How do I create a list or urls from an Amazon AWS bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm able to list all of the objects in my bucket, but it's in this format:

2018-11-18 11:53:57      28256 2.mp3
2018-11-18 11:53:59      28673 3.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:00      28673 4.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:01      30341 5.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:02      30343 6.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:03      30347 7.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:04      29513 8.mp3
2018-11-18 11:54:05      26594 9.mp3

I have hundreds of these files and they all share the same root url:

For example 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/Foldername/0.mp3
https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/Foldername/1.mp3 
etc

How can I isolate the #.mp3 and concat that with the base url 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketName/Foldername/'?

I'm trying to avoid copying hundreds of the links by hand! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What do you want to do with the list of links once your have concatenated them? Personally, I often use the `&` operator in Excel to join URLs.

Comment: Hi John, they're links for my website. Ha, that's funny. I actually tried excel first and then decided to try to figure it out with code. I'll give excel another shot until I can figure it out with wizardry.

Comment: Just be careful with the spaces. They might give you problems with the URLs. You might need to substitute `+` for each space.